# as.character(as.Date()) returns NA in shiny datatable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shiny-server

The following code works in datatable display:

```
observe({
if (!any(input$date == "NA")) {
  dates <- isolate(as.Date(dataset$data[, input$date], format = input$dateformat))
}

if (!any(input$date == "NA")) {
  dataset$data[, input$date] <- dates
}
```

However, the `dataset$date` (date column) is saved in date format. I want to save it in character format. Here's my attempt:

```
observe({
if (!any(input$date == "NA")) {
  dates <- isolate(as.Date(dataset$data[, input$date], format = input$dateformat))
}

if (!any(input$date == "NA")) {
  dataset$data[, input$date] <- as.character(dates)
}
```

This gives me all NA values for the date column. Any thoughts on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

P.S. I'm not sure if the `isolate` is needed in this case, that was just my latest attempt, I've tried different versions such as the basic `as.character(as.Date())`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `is.na()` instead of `== "NA"`? Unless of course you have `"NA"` strings. I'm genuinely asking because I'm not very familiar with data.table nor shiny.

Comment: @Molx, only because ```input$date``` comes from ```selectInput``` which I believe gives a character value

Comment: Try using the package "lubridate" to convert back and forth date & character formats easily.